# How to respond in the rebuttal phase when the reviewer's concern is a blind review issue?

Tags: peer-review, conference, paper-submission

I recently received the reviewers' feedback for my paper and I need to respond them in their questions in the rebuttal phase.
One reviewer (who also gave me a weak reject) mentioned that one of my references infringes the blind-review policy of the conference.

Well, I cited my paper Y, which is recently accepted in the upcoming conference X, without using my name, but I mentioned the name of the paper and the conference as well. I was confident that the final notifications would be announced before the conference X takes place, however, i didn't consider the fact that conferences would announce their accepted papers on their website 1-2 months prior to the conference! :D

I think the reviewer tried to investigate further and went to the program of that conference and searched for paper Y to find the name of the authors!

I do not know what to respond regarding this comment to avoid my paper from being rejected by the PC and also to satisfy the reviewer's concern?!

Answer (score 4):

**Ignore it**.

Even if  your paper infringes the blind-review policy of the conference, it doesn't change the veracity of the results. It could, conceivably, have led to a desk reject without sending for review, but the editor clearly did not pick up on it, for he sent it for review anyway.

The reviewer's comment was as much a reminder to you as it was to the editor. Perhaps the editor should not have sent it for review, but since he already has, what's done cannot be undone. Just ignore it, and treat the rest of the comments.

Comment: But if i do not mention that in my author response, doesn't the reviewer gets annoyed? I mean shouldn't i apologize or mention that it was a mistake and i didn't consider that the other conference would announce their program and ...